# JQuery Angular form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular

I just started with angular to build a web app, I am using this Template [Front][1], and inside this template, they are using Jquery to toggle password text and validate forms as in the following code:

```
 <!-- JS Plugins Init. -->
<script>
  $(document).on('ready', function () {
    // INITIALIZATION OF SHOW PASSWORD
    // =======================================================
    $('.js-toggle-password').each(function () {
      new HSTogglePassword(this).init()
    });

    // INITIALIZATION OF FORM VALIDATION
    // =======================================================
    $('.js-validate').each(function() {
      $.HSCore.components.HSValidation.init($(this));
    });
  });
</script>
```

this is from my `sign-in.component.html` of course this is no working, and I am having a hard time figuring out how and what is the best way of making this work in angular, this is what I have tried and it failed:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "../../shared/services/auth.service";
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sign-in',
  templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
 })
export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(
public authService: AuthService
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {

  $('.js-validate').each(function() {
     ($ as any).HSCore.components.HSValidation.init($(this));
  });

 }

}
```

Here is what I am using:

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.14
Node: 14.15.4
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.2.14
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.14
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.14
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.14
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.14
@angular/fire                   6.1.5
@schematics/angular             11.2.14
@schematics/update              0.1102.14
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.1.6
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could show me the best practice to solve this problem.
[1]: https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v1.3/html/home/index.html

Comment: Don't mix angular and jQuery, there is no need for this. Like at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different approaches used in angular to handling user inputs through forms: template-driven or reactive. For using any technique you have import that module in **app.module.ts** file. For submit the form **(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"** directive is used on form tag. You can create a template variable for accessing the overall form or you can use **[(ngModel)]** directive.

Useful Links:

- [Introduction to forms in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview)
- [template-driven form](https://angular.io/guide/forms)
- [Reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)